# How get Row Index in a SQL Database using entity framework without query all data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

We do have a database with thousand of entries. we would like to get the "ranked position" for a specific item by its name.

Since there is a lot of data we would like to avoid bring query ALL data in order to determine row index (using `ToList()` and `IndexOf()` for instance).

I tried using

```
        List<Ranking> ranking = _context.Testes
           .OrderByDescending(t => t.Val)
           .Select((d, i) => new Ranking() {
               Name = d.Name,
               Ranking= i
           }).First(d=>d.Name = "Test");
```

but I got this error:

> 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[WebApplication4.Models.Teste]).OrderByDescending(t => t.Val).Select((d, i) => new Ranking() {Name = d.Name, Ranking = i})': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Paging with Skip and Take?

Comment: Skip and take will get the nth position of the list. I would like to provide a "Name" and query the ranked position of it.

Comment: You can't translate this `Select()` overload to SQL. ORMs aren't meant for reporting and this is 100% a reporting query. SQL Server offers ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`. You could create a view that calculates the rank and map your rankings to it, eg `CREATE VIEW Rankings AS SELECT Name,RANK OVER(ORDER BY Val) Ranking From Tests`. EF will probably map the `Ranking` class to the `Rankings` view by convention. If not, you map it using the `Table` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't translate this Select() overload to SQL. ORMs aren't meant for reporting and this is 100% a reporting query.

SQL Server offers [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql) like ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK. You could create a view that calculates the rank and map your rankings to it, eg :

```
CREATE VIEW Rankings 
AS 
SELECT 
    Name,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Val) Ranking 
From Tests
```

`DENSE_RANK()` will return the same rank number if two records tie and continue with the next rank number. ROW_NUMBER will just use incrementing numbers. If you use `ROW_NUMBER` you should probably use additional sorting critera to avoid generating random rankings for ties.

EF will probably map the Ranking class to the Rankings view by convention. If not, you map it using the Table attribute or `ToTable` if you use Code-First configuration :

```
[Table("Rankings")
public class Ranking
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Ranking {get;set;}
}
```

Retrieving a specific ranking requires only a `Where()` clause:

```
var someRanking=context.Rankings.Where(r=>r.Name=someName);
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ something like (note you must handle ties to get a well-defined ranking)

```
            var q = from t in db.Testes
                    where t.Name == "whatever"
                    select new
                      {
                        Testes =t,
                        Rank =1+db.Testes.Where(ot => ot.Val < t.Val || (ot.Val == t.Val && ot.Id < t.Id) ).Count()
                      };
```

which translates to

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Val] AS [Val], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    1 + [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Val] AS [Val], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Testes] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[Val] < [Extent1].[Val]) OR (([Extent2].[Val] = [Extent1].[Val]) AND ([Extent2].[Id] < [Extent1].[Id]))) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Testes] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE N'whatever' = [Extent1].[Name]
    )  AS [Project1]
```